# Groovy code doesn't work properly

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I want to get one flowFile at first, `def flowFile=session.get(1)` as I know it   will return a list of flowFile in which there will be one flowFile. Then I want to get some data from it and remove this session.

After that I want to get file with certain name and if they don't match this name I want to remove or rollback the session (which one is best case for this task?) but when I run this code it doesn't throw an exception but doesn't make any job.

1. what should I change?
2. Should I use `session.remove()` or rollback which one is better for pulling back unmatched flowfiles?

Here is my code:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import java.lang.*

def flowFile= session.get(1)
def name=""
def count=0
def value=0

List<FlowFile> flowFiles = new ArrayList<FlowFile>()

for(def k in flowFile) {
  name = k.getAttribute("realName")
  count = k.getAttribute("amount")
  value = count as  Number
  value = Math.round(value)
  session.remove(k)
  flowFile.clear()
}

def flowFile1 = session.get();

if(flowFile1.getAttribute("filename").substring(0,10) == name) {
  flowFiles.add(flowFile1)
} else {
  session.remove(flowFile1) 
}

if(flowFiles.size() == value) {
  for( def m in flowFiles) {
    session.transfer(m,REL_SUCCESS)
  }

  flowFiles.clear()
}
```

Comment: How  can  i  be  sure  that  this  flowfile def flowFile= session.get(1)  is  receved  only  once?

Comment: I think the problem needs more context and explaination

Comment: I want  to get    one  flowFile  to  read  from  it   count attribute and  then  is  want  to  get  count  number  flowfiles  and  put  it  in flowfile  List   after  that  i  will  checkk  if  flowfile  list  size== count   i  will transfer  all  receveied  flowfiles